# Speed up scrolling text

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have this function that scrolls text from right to left.
I want to speed up the scrolling, I tried modifying the `1/100` but nothing changes.

Any tips? 

Thanks in adavnce.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var marquee = $('div.marquee');
    console.log(marquee);
    marquee.each(function() {
        var mar = $(this),indent = mar.width();
        mar.marquee = function() {
            indent--;
            mar.css('text-indent',indent);
            if (indent < -1 * mar.children('p').width()) {
                indent = mar.width();
            }
        };
        mar.data('interval',setInterval(mar.marquee,1/100));
    });
});
```

```css
.marquee {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px 0;
    height:1.2em;
    width:100vw;
    font-family:'super';
}
.marquee p {
 display:inline;
    white-space:nowrap;
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=marquee>
<p>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Increase the decrement of `indent`.

Comment: Are you aware that the second argument to `setInterval` is the time delay in *milliseconds*? Even a value of 1 will make it happen a thousand times a second, 1/100 will be 100,000 times a second! I don't actually know if the function will accept fractional values for this delay parameter, and if not what happens if you try to pass it one - but this probably isn't doing what you expect it to. As @Teemu says, the best way to make this appear visually quicker is to decrement `indent` by more than 1 - and then give the `setInterval` a time interval of say 10-50ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that changes how fast the marquee is moving is the `indent--` line in your code. The indent is decreasing so the object is moving to the left. To change your speed, you can do something like `indent = indent - K`, where K is a value that describes your speed.

Below you can see a small example. I added two buttons that help you to control the speed. Hope it helps! Cheers!

```js
var marqueeSpeed = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var marquee = $('div.marquee');
    marquee.each(function() {
        var mar = $(this),indent = mar.width();
        mar.marquee = function() {
            indent = indent - marqueeSpeed;
            mar.css('text-indent',indent);
            if (indent < -1 * mar.children('p').width()) {
                indent = mar.width();
            }
        };
        
        mar.data('interval', setInterval(mar.marquee, 1/100));
    });
});

var increase = function() {
    ++marqueeSpeed;
}

var decrease = function() {
    if (marqueeSpeed > 0) {
        --marqueeSpeed;
    }
}
```

```css
.marquee {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px 0;
    height:1.2em;
    width:100vw;
    font-family:'super';
}
.marquee p {
 display:inline;
    white-space:nowrap;
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=marquee>
<p>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</p>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<button onclick="increase()">Increase speed</button>
<button onclick="decrease()">Decrease speed</button>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Also, I recommend you to read about `requestAnimationFrame`, that may help you not to use an interval anymore. Cheers!